# Apple watch page indicator delayed

Tags: ios, segue, apple-watch

I've successfully implemented "next page" relationship between interface controllers on apple watch.

I've encountered a problem while changing the pages. The page indicator switches with a delay of about 0,5-1s after the second interface controller is shown (animation finished).

It is transition between 2 simple page controllers with only 1 label inside.

What could be the reason? I've compared with the apple's activity app and there the indicator switches right after the transition animation has finished.